# Is there an Apex code formatting standard?

Tags: apex, compile-error

Are there any documents out there that talk about proper formatting in apex? I have not been able to find too much on this subject (maybe my google skills are weak).

Some examples:

```
 //comment with no space
 // comment with space

 if (something == something) { String foo = "keep it in one?"; }

 if(something==something)
      String foo="Or do it this way?";
```

I realize that this is probably based off of the user's preference, but I'm wondering if there is a standard to do things a certain way in apex? Would writing the syntax one way or the other affect the performance?

Comment: There's a notable question somewhere on here - I did a quick search and couldn't find it, but it pretty much says "follow Java standards."

Comment: Unless someone beats me to it, I'll post the link in an hour or so. Note that it's an unofficial standard. The salesforce.com team prefers Java syntax straight up.

Comment: Yes, Java standards needs to be followed here as mentioned earlier. Also, I do not think formatting/Indentation will have any impact on performance. It is more for readability and maintenance perspective. Performance will depend on how you use/define the code, just as an example, see this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80654/syntactic-vs-performance-difference-on-object-creation

Comment: https://github.com/PolarisProject/salesforceStyleGuide/ is a style guide being written (and is found on another question/answer here). I myself am working on some open-source stuff, including a guide of my own, but focused more on optimization and legibility.

Comment: Nice link. Was reading the guide and it seems that could turn into something useful. I personally use "Atom" as my text editor and a plugin would be great for apex. If the plugin would replace 4 spaces with a \t would also be a useful feature. And then formatting your code for you. Could be a good side project of mine now that i think of it. Great responses everyone. Very helpful

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like others have said, you pretty much keep to Java standards.  The only thing that is 'Apex Specific' I would say is line indentation.  You want to always use tabs for indentation instead of spaces specifically in Apex/VF mainly because there is a character count for orgs.  This may not seem like a big deal but you never know what may happen in the future if the org you are working with ends up getting an extremely large code base.

Comment: I missed that from my answer! - It is important to take character count into account (pardon the pun) especially when working on a large product!

Comment: I reduced ~1,000,000 characters to about ~766,000 in a code base I inherited in about 30 seconds simply replacing four spaces with tab characters in the Force.com IDE (Search > File > Regexp search four spaces, replace with \t). It's simple, and highly effective.

Comment: Replacing spaces with tabs to save space. Am I back in the 1980s? Gotta love this platform. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

The examples you have provided will not affect performance in anyway. However writing good code is important, it's worth taking a look at the [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) to ensure you are writing efficient apex.